# Yii2: Why kartik\select2 widget not filled then I trying update model?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, widget

Im have ActiveRecord model and view for update form of this model. Also I have getter and setter in model class that looks like this

```
public function setTopvisorGoogleRegion($value)
{
    $this->myvalue = $value;
    return(true);
}

public function getTopvisorGoogleRegion()
{
    return([1 => '123']); //I return this array for show you essence of the problem
}
```

Following logic in this code $model->topvisorgoogleregion must return [1 => '123']

In view I have next code

```
<?php echo($form->field($model, topvisorgoogleregion)->textInput());?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'topvisorgoogleregion')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' =>  [1 => '123', 2 => '456'],
    'options' => [
        'id'=>'projectCtrl',
        'placeholder' => 'Select option',
        'multiple' => true
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'tags' => true, 
    ],

]);
?>
```

When I open form I want to see option 1 => '123' already selected in Select2. Its logically because when already existing record is updating, ActiveRecord get data that already stored in model (in this case using getter) and fill fields in view with this data (In first field that using textInput I see text 'Array' because getter in model returns array). But Select2 is empty when I open update page. Whats going wrong?

If I delete first field (textInput) nothing changes

Comment: not sure what you are doing you are passing an assoc array to the `attribute` name parameter of the `field` function ?

Comment: Try returning a scalar value from the getter (i.e. `return 1;` instead of `return [1 => '123'];`)

Comment: No, I dont try pass it into attribute name parameter. I want when page loads in select2 show "123" element selected by default.

P.S: You are right, I find typo, I lose quotes in first string of second code fragment when copy it to stackoverflow, but with quotes I see the same

Comment: xtx, I try to return scalar value, it doesnt affect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution - in getter I need provide ActiveQuery object, not array. I dont know why and how it works, but it works